# Can't establish connection between android socketio client to socketio server

Tags: android, node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I'm trying to develop a chat app with Socket.IO.
My server side is Node.js with express + socket.io libraries installed and my client side is Android + Web.

I tried using at my client side all of these jars:

1. 'com.github.nkzawa:socket.io-client:0.3.0' - Which is found at socket.io website tutorial on making a android to socketio server.
2. 'io.socket:socket.io-client:0.6.1' - Which is found at nkzawa android chat demo repository.
3. 'com.github.nkzawa:socket.io-client:0.6.0' - another version in the past that worked for me.

All of these jars didn't work for the android side.
On my server side i have the latest version - 1.3.7 of Socket.IO library and i tried each of the jars above to connect to it.

I also tried using Socket.IO version 1.3.6 that worked for me in the past with the 3rd jar on the list.

Plus i tried changing the url in the android side to http://10.0.2.2:3000 , http://192.168.1.100:3000 on each of these jars versions...

Notes -

1. Note - i am working with genymotion in Android.
2. I have INTERNET_PERMISSION.
3. The socket.io on the server side works on web browser(local pc).

***This is my server side:***

```
var app = require('express')();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));

io.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log(socket.id);
    console.log('Client connected');
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('listening on port 3000');
});
```

***This is my client side :***

```
 private Socket mSocket;
    {
        try {
            mSocket = IO.socket("http://10.0.3.2:3000");
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mSocket.connect();
        //setupActivity();
    }
```

I got to the point that i am really clueless to what to do next , so any help will help me right now :)
Thanks

***Edit - 
The problem has been solved. Apparently genymotion doesn't need the 10.0.3.2 ip to connect to localhost so I entered my pc ip address and it worked.
By the way I didn't thought about connection remotely , that way i could have eliminate the problem and know that the problem is connecting with the ip address.***

Comment: Mark solution correct below so that people see that it is solved.

Answer (score 0):

Solution Goes here, I almost missed it because it wasn't where it was supposed to be.
(credit to OP: Ido Magor):

The problem has been solved. Apparently genymotion doesn't need the 10.0.3.2 ip to connect to localhost so I entered my pc ip address and it worked. By the way I didn't thought about connection remotely , that way i could have eliminate the problem and know that the problem is connecting with the ip address.